# scale image in table github markdown

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

I'm using Jeckyll to render a GitHub-flavoured markdown table (at least I think that's an accurate description). I'm using this [Jeckyll theme](https://github.com/tomjoht/documentation-theme-jekyll)

**How to scale images within the table?** I tried two things:

```
| I say          | You say   | Example image  |
|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
| Hello | Goodbye| ![dummy](images/example-studies/Screenshot_gonogo.png){:width="50"}|
| Hello | Goodbye|  {% include image.html file="pathToImg/img.png" alt="img" max-width="200" %}|
| Hello | Goodbye|  {% include image.html file="pathToImg/img.png" alt="img" max-width="200" %}|
```

The version in the first row (`![dummy](pathToImage/image.png){:width="50"}`) doesn't work. (See first row in the screenshot below).

The version on rows 2 and 3 (`{% include image.html file="pathToImage/image.png" alt="alt text" max-width="200" %}`) does work, but I get an extra line in the rendered table.

This extra line does not appear in the GitHub preview, so I think it's a Jeckyll issue.

[image: rendered result]

[image: github preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML tags in markdown. Try using `<img src="my/image/path"/>` within your table.